# Нужна ли запятая? (4)

Tags: пунктуация

*По результатам проведенной экспертизы работ(,) жюри конкурса...*

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того, что Вы хотели сказать. 
Если речь шла о работах жюри конкурса (ну, мало ли, вдруг жюри конкурса с свободное от судейства время что-то там создает), и теперь есть результаты экспертизы этих работ, то запятая не нужна:

> По результатам проведенной экспертизы (*экспертизы чего?*) **работ жюри конкурса** ...

Если же вы хотели сказать, что жюри приняло какое-то решение по результатам проведенной этим жюри экспертизы работы неназванных третьих лиц, то запятая нужна:

> По результатам проведенной экспертизы работ, (*кто что-то сделал по этим результатам*) **жюри конкурса**...

Comment: *По результатам проведенной экспертизы (экспертизы чего?) работ жюри конкурса* - остроумно, но не реалистично. У жюри есть только одна работа - оценивать участников.

Comment: @behemothus, однажды я был участником похожей ситуации. В бытность мою фотокором местной газеты, меня пригласили в жюри городского фотоконкурса для учащихся школ. Организаторы конкурса попросили всех участников жюри принести хотя бы несколько своих собственных работ, из которых в результате был сформирован отдельный стенд. И вдруг, после оглашения итогов основного конкурса, организаторы решили сделать нам своеобразный "сюрприз", предложив зрительному залу выбрать лучшую работу на стенде жюри. Я тогда не выиграл, т.к. не догадывался о таком "конкурсе" и взял с собой не самые эффектные работы ;)

Comment: тогда с вами еще хуже. ))) Вы как сочетание "работы жюри конкурса" понимаете? Неужели как *ваши* работы?!

Comment: @behemothus, это был просто пример из жизни, не более того :) И я, разумеется, понимаю, какое значение имелось в виду в изначальном вопросе. А два возможных значения этого фрагмента фразы я привел исключительно для того, чтобы показать, как запятая помогает избежать неоднозначности толкования.

Comment: я вас спраширваю про пример их русского языка. Что ві подумаете про человека, назвавшего те работі о которых вы рассказали "работами жюри"? Я подумаю, что он как минимум косноязычный. Это "работы **членов** жюри". -----  До сих пор не покидает ощущение, что это стёб.  Замените жюри на предприятие. И что? Доходы сотрудников - это доходы предприятия?

Comment: @behemothus, насчет косноязычности - конечно, согласен. Ощущение было бы именно таким.

Answer (score 0):

Рассматривается только один случай из описанных Иваном (второй), но и в нём запятая не нужна.